# How to paginate getting bulk data from firebase with axios?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, axios, nuxt.js

Assuming I have 1000+ blog posts. What will be the best practice to get data from firebase using axios to store in nuxtServerInit?

Can I somehow get the first 10 blog posts first during the first load and get even more data later on?

Right now I have vuex action as following:

```
nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    return axios
      .get('https://my-blog.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
      .then(res => {
        const postsArray = []
        for (const key in res.data) {
          postsArray.push({ ...res.data[key], uid: key })
        }
        vuexContext.commit('setPosts', postsArray)
      })
      .catch(e => context.error(e))
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the [REST API to access the Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data). To retrieve a limited number of items, use a [limit query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#limit-queries).

```
https://my-blog.firebaseio.com/posts.json?limitToFirst=10
```

Since a limit only makes sense when you know how the items are order, you'll want to also [order the items](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-key), i.e. on their key:

```
https://my-blog.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy="$key"&limitToFirst=10
```

Note that the results may not be ordered, since the order of properties in a JSON object is undefined. So the result **will** contains the first 10 posts, but it **may** not show them in the right order.

Next step is to get the next 10 items. Unlike on most traditional databases, Firebase doesn't support an offset clause on its queries. So you can't tell it to skip the first 10 items to get to the next 10.

Instead [Firebase queries use anchors/ranges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#range-queries): you must know the last item of the previous page to build the query for the next page. Say that the 10th post had a key of `keyOfPost10`, then you can get the next page with:

```
https://my-blog.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="keyOfPost10"&limitToFirst=11
```

We need to retrieve 11 posts here, since we're also getting the 10th post. That also means you'll need to filter the overlapping post in your client code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hmmmm. Seem like it getting complicated when Firebase doesn't support offset. The key is the id that firebase auto-generated. So I have no idea how to handle that.

Comment: You'll have to remember the last key of each page you've shown. Search for a few previous questions on Firebase and pagination and you should find plenty of examples. If you're having problems implementing it with what I've shown, post what you've tried.